# Another If-else-then statment in bash

Tags: bash, shell, loops, if-statement

I am running to a "weird" "if then else" problem (or I am just a novice). Or, I do not fully understand the semantics of specified statement.

What I want to do is read through a table (csv) like the one below

```
/home/trotos/I16_1505_09.fastq.gz,34,hg19
/home/trotos/I16_1505_06.fastq.gz,34,hg19
/home/trotos/I16_1505_12.fastq.gz,40,hg19
/home/trotos/I15_1277_01.fastq.gz,42,gg5
/home/trotos/I15_1458_01.fastq.gz,42,gg5
/home/trotos/I15_1314_01.fastq.gz,36,gg5
/home/trotos/I15_1458_03.fastq.gz,36,gg5
```

and then use input from each column (sequentially) to perform several commands.
the script I am using (not refined yet) where file is the statedcsv

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob


file="$3"
human="$1"
mouse="$2"

while IFS=, read col1 col2 col3 ; do  # the file need to be loaded at the end of the loop, check a done
    echo $col1
    echo $col2
    echo $col3

for i in $col1; do

if [$col3="hg19"]
    then
       ref_genome=$human
echo "1"
echo $ref_genome
    else
        ref_genome=$mouse
echo "2"
echo $ref_genome

fi
echo $ref_genome
echo "....."

done
done < $file
```

the command is the following

```
./test '/home/trotos/Downloads/chromosomes/hg19.fa' '/home/trotos/Downloads/chromosomes/gg5.fa.gz' 'csv_file'
```

What it does correctly is to read the columns of the file, and get the data I need from a column per line in a loop.

But when I am using the third column (hg19 or gg5) as a statement of TRUE or FALSE to get a different condition:

> if hg19 is TRUE then 'hg19.fa' is the correct
>
> if gg5 is TRUE then 'gg5.fa.gz' is the correct
>   but script's output differs:

```
LOOP
/home/trotos/lane2_I15_1458_08.fastq.gz
42
**gg5**
/home/trotos/lane2_I15_1458_08.fastq.gz
/home/trotos/lane2_I15_1458_08.fastq
/home/trotos/lane2_I15_1458_08

....
1
**/home/trotos/Downloads/chromosomes/hg19.fa**
.....
END LOOP
```

The first problem is that when col3==hg19 it gives the correct output that would be "/home/trotos/Downloads/chromosomes_hg19/hg19.fa". But when col3==gg5 i still get the same "/home/trotos/Downloads/chromosomes_hg19/hg19.fa".
*So who will I get the correct answer?*
The second is how to use the "if then else" statement to get the specific file that corresponds to the 3rd column and *to use that information inside the loop defined by:*

```
 for i in $col1; do.
```

Thank you in advance.
I hope my description will not confuse you.

Comment: It would be great if you could cut down your script to provide us with a [mcve], i.e. by removing all the "debug" echoes and comments. At first glance, `[$col3="hg19"]` is wrong, since you need spaces like `[ "$col3" = hg19 ]`, but that might not be the only problem.

Comment: script is cleaner, I added the spaces and it appears to work. but also spaces are needed between the "=".

Comment: Yes, they sure are!